# BindingSeq and Constants in Binding.scala?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, scala.js, binding.scala

- `Binding` is `val` of `Var`.
- `BindingSeq` should also be `val` of `Vars`.

But, to construct sequence of Binding, the `BindingSeq` can not be constructed from sequence. 
Is there something wrong?

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding
import com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.{BindingSeq, Var, Vars}

val x1: Var[Int] = Var{1}
val x2: Binding[Int] = Binding{1}
val x3: Vars[Int] = Vars{Seq(1,2,3): _*}
val x4: BindingSeq[Int] = BindingSeq{Seq(1,2,3): _*}
ScalaFiddle.scala:18: error: .this.com.thoughtworks.binding.Binding.BindingSeq.type does not take parameters
  val x4: BindingSeq[Int] = BindingSeq{Seq(1,2,3): _*}
```

Comment: Good point, despite of the fact that `Binding` is not actually a `val` of `Var`. Would you like to create a Pull Request to add the feature?

Comment: :) Would like too if have time someday.  Is the right wording be "Binding is a immutable of Var"?

Comment: https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/blob/01c7c16/Binding/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/binding/Binding.scala#L387 See, `class Var extends Binding`